# Convert macaddress to uppercase bash

Tags: bash

I need to compare 1 mac with other but 1 mac is in lowercase and other is Uppercase, so using grep i cant compare eachothter. Help please Thanks

Example (e4:42:a6:4d:a1:57  to  E4:42:A6:4D:A1:57)

Comment: `grep -i` is case insensitive. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, it is, but I suspect that you don't need to. Please [edit] your question to provide some more context and include any things you've already tried.

Comment: Yes it works , Thanks alot